# Django admin page combobox, possible?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a simple model in django with a field using choices. As it is now, I am forced to use one of the available choices, how can I be able to use those choices and also be able to enter text manually?

```
WHERE_CHOICES = (
    ('CHL', 'Center HL'),
    ('CHD', 'Center HD')
)

class Event(models.Model):
    ev_start = models.DateTimeField()
    ev_end = models.DateTimeField()
    where = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='CHL', choices=WHERE_CHOICES)
```

Thanks

Comment: You could customize the admin widget for the field, here's an example on how to add select2 for example: https://github.com/asyncee/django-easy-select2

Answer (score 0):

You can override the admin form field widget with a `datalist` tag.

It would look like that (using the `floppyforms` library):

```
class EventAdminForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = "__all__" 
        widgets = {
            'where': floppyforms.widgets.Input(datalist=[v[0] for v in Event.WHERE_CHOICES])
        }


class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  form = EventAdminForm

admin.site.register(Event, EventAdmin)
```

Comment: kinda struggling a bit.

https://pastebin.com/Sha50A54

a bit more help please. Thanks